# Setting the default group for a SharePoint site programatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Using the web interface, you can set a group to be the default group for a site by selecting Settings->Make Default Group on the list view for the group.

Is there a way to do this programatically using SharePoint Web Services or the new Client Object Model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This option sets the [**SPWeb.AssociatedMemberGroup**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.associatedmembergroup.aspx) property:

```
using (SPWeb web = ...)
{
  web.AssociatedMemberGroup = someGroup;
  web.Update();
}
```

*You can use .NET Reflector to check it yourself - decompile the `Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.dll` assembly and find the `BtnMakeDefaultGroup_Click` method in the `PeoplePage` class.*

Comment: To be fair, that doesn't actually help the OP with working out how to accomplish this via SharePoint web services or the client OM.

Comment: @NickCox: You're right! I must have focused on the *set programatically* part and skipped the other requirements.